# Is there any Master or Ph.D. programme that involves Mathematics, Philosophy and Biology?

Tags: phd, masters, mathematics, biology, philosophy

I majored in Business and Economics a few years ago and right now I'm looking for a master or PhD in Mathematics because I am quite passionate about it, but I just don't really know in which program and/or university I should apply, because what I want is kind of a relationship between Mathematics, Philosophy and Biology.

After finishing my degree I realised that Mathematics is what I truly hungered for and which motivated me. I feel the need to understand the existence of the universe as it is. I am a seeker of the truth, and the only thing I know is true is Mathematics, so I want to give my brain and life a good use, not for the mundane.

Im aware that human behaviour is mostly a reflection of nature, I want to understand nature by learning the universal language of Mathematics.

I need some advice in the following questions:

1. Is there any well-known Master or Ph.D. programme that can englobe Mathematics, Philosophy and Biology?
2. Although I did not take any Mathematics minor, should I go first to the Masters or go directly to the Ph.D.?

Lastly, I am free to study anywhere in the world.

Comment: Have you read about *mathematical biology*?

Comment: Topics that come to mind are public health, epidemiology, biostatistics, bioethics, and medical ethics.